# how can i create multiple recipients of status messages

Tags: users

Is there a way where I can share statuses to multiple recipients in Drupal7 using statuses module (microblog)
It would be great if someone can point me out how to send messages to any of relation only if I am using UR module.

Regards,
Yatendra